# How to have multiple hidden divs with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a search engine with bootstrap. I want to have multiple pages of results, each in its own `div`, with only the active `div` displayed. I have a non-responsive version of the code running without bootstrap.

I define this style:

```
.hiddenDiv {
  display: none;
}
.visibleDiv {
  display: block;
  border: none;
}
```

I have this code to manage the showing/hiding of divs.

```
var lastDiv = "";    
function showDiv(divName) {
  // hide last div 
    document.getElementById(lastDiv).className = "hiddenDiv";
}

//if value of the box is not nothing and an object with that name exists, then change the class 
if (divName && document.getElementById(divName)) {
  document.getElementById(divName).className = "visibleDiv";
  lastDiv = divName;   
}
```

I show the div with the first page of results when the page body is loaded.

```
<body onload="showDiv('page_1')">
```

And, I trigger the js code when the user clicks on a page link.

```
<a onClick='return showDiv("page_2");' href="#">2</a>
```

This all works fine. I'm wondering what the bootstrap way is to do this?

I see that bootstrap offers a pagination class. So, I can modify the `showDiv` function and the call to it to handle making the page links in the bootstrap list items enabled or not. I'm wondering if there is a better way in bootstrap to manage the showing/hiding of the divs.

Comment: p.s. I've seen examples of bootstrap showing/hiding one div, e.g. for showing one header or another based on device but not an example of managing multiple divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap actually uses jquery which it depends on for most of its functions..

Instead of building a class to show your div you can use jquery's show/hide methods.

for an example:

```
$('element,class, or ID').click(function(){
$('#page2').show();
})
```

OR to be more advance you could load pages dynamically within a div using jquery.load

for an example:

```
/*I would recommend wrapping your pagination in a class for accurate targeting */

$('.pagination a').click(function(){
var page = $(this).val() /*assuming your inner html is a number */
$('div').load("index" + page + ".html");

})
```

Comment: Good idea. Think jquery rather than js. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could assign all your divs a class say form example `<div class="result-div"></div>`
so your diferent divs will look like this.

```
<div class="result-div" id="result-1" data-id="1"></div>
<div class="result-div" id="result-2" data-id="2"></div>
<div class="result-div" id="result-n" data-id="3"></div>
```

then where ever you put your navigation, it might look like this

```
<a href="#1" data-show="1" class="results-nav">1</a>
<a href="#2" data-show="2" class="results-nav">2</a>
<a href="#n" data-show="n" class="results-nav">n</a>
```

there is a reason why I have decided to use both `id` and `data-id`
with jquery, you can hide the divs before the page finishes loading like this

```
$(function(){
    $('.result-div').hide();//hide all the results
    $('.result-div[data-id="1"]').show();//show the first one
});
```

or by implementing using the CSS you used, it will look like this

```
$(function(){
    $('.result-div').addClass('hiddenDiv');
    $('.result-div[data-id="1"]').removeClass('hiddenDiv');//show the first one
});
```

to show the first div you can alternatively use the id since its unique

```
$('#result-1').show();//show the first one
```

then once the user clicks the navigation item you can show the desired and hide the rest. This is where the id problem comes in with some Jquery Versions.
so we handle the click event and do like so

```
$(".results-nav").click(function(){
    $('.result-div').addClass('hiddenDiv');//hide all
    $('#result-'+$(this).attr("data-id")).removeClass('hiddenDiv');//show the first one
});
```

what we are doing above is that we are showing the target div by tracking using data-id of the clicked element.
which is part of the corresponding element's id.

The Problem with using the this is that some version of jquery will throw an error when you try to use the id attribute for that kind of operation. So I think the preferred option will be to use data-id attribute because it does not return an error. So

```
$(".results-nav").click(function(){
    $('.result-div').addClass('hiddenDiv');//hide all
    $('.result-div[data-id="'+$(this).attr("data-id")+'"]').removeClass('hiddenDiv');//show the first one
});
```

and of course you can replace `.removeClass('hiddenDiv')` with `.show('')` and `addClass('hiddenDiv')` with  `hide('');`

**Also, note** that using the below code as I mentioned above might cause all the divs to show for a few milliseconds before hiding.

```
$(function(){
    $('.result-div').addClass('hiddenDiv');
    $('.result-div[data-id="1"]').removeClass('hiddenDiv');//show the first one
});
```

so by you can have the hiddenDiv in you HTML by default then only remove the first one when the page loads

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.result-div').addClass('hiddenDiv');
    $('.result-div[data-id="1"]').removeClass('hiddenDiv');//show the first one
});
```

**To Conclude** I honestly do not see the reason why you want to have all your results div in one page. it will increase load time you know.

i think investing time in some backend language like php will be worth it